# Unable to select the value from dropdown... selenium is unable to find the element using the mentioned xpath which i have copied using chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="ext-gen428" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: visible; left: 252px; top: 324px; width: 130px; height: 100px;">

   <div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen430" style="width: 130px; overflow: auto; height: 100px;">

        <div class="x-combo-list-item ">ANY</div>

        <div class="x-combo-list-item ">BASFID</div>

        <div class="x-combo-list-item ">EBID</div>

         <div class="x-combo-list-item ">SAPNUM</div>

         <div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">GLNID</div>

          </div></div>
```

I used this (//*[@id="ext-gen430"]/div[2] )xpath to select BASFID...but selenium is unable to find this element

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Include the code in the text of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this `gen` bit in your `ext-gen430` [ID](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) attribute implies that the ID is **generated** therefore it might be dynamic and changed each time you open or deploy the application.

Therefore I would recommend sticking to the `x-combo-list-inner` [class attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) like:

```
//div[@class='x-combo-list-inner']/div[2]
```

Alternatively if you want just the option with `BASFID` text - you can match it directly:

```
//div[text()='BASFID']
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)